# create book from filesystem

Tags: bash, filesystems, organization

A file system that represents a book with a directory representing each chapter and each chapter section, where each page/.png file is in the directory as the p page of section q of chapter n. Page one would be listed as 0/0/0 but page 456 might be the third chapter, and the second section's page 4 making it 2/1/3 from the directory containing all of the other pages/.png files.

How would a bash script recursively search through each directory and organize the corresponding pages into the right page where the file system could be read like a book/pdf? So that page 1 (0/0/0 in the file system) would be in a new directory with a shiny label displaying 1 or 001 while page/file 456 (2/1/3) would be displayed as a wonderful 456?

I've found a couple similar problems that use something like the following,

```
find . type -d | while read -r d '' file; do mv .'{$d} done
```

Which finds the directories within . but gets stuck renaming the files. So I hunted down the following script.

source

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
list=find `"path/to . " -type d`
    for directory in $list; do
    echo "directory=$directory"
    cd $directory
    imglist="ls | grep '\.png'"
    for file in $imglist; do
        mv home/
    done
    cd
done
#I didn't write either of these
```

But is only good for two levels.

So how best to make it go from messy file system to one simplified directory.

Comment: Could you make it clearer what the input directory structure is and how the output should be determined from it? It's not clear to me why `0/0/0` should map to `1` and `2/1/3` should map to `456`. A smaller scale example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the following could help

```
bookroot='.' #the directory where are the chapters
final="./finalbook" #the destination

pages=( $(find "$bookroot"/[0-9]* -name \*.png -print | sed "s:$bookroot/::" | sort -t/ -k1n -k2n -k3n) )
for i in "${!pages[@]}"
do 
    echo cp "$bookroot/${pages[$i]}" "$final/$((i+1))_of_${#pages[@]}.png"
done
```

This is dry run. If satisfied, remove the `echo`.